# Add Additional Column in "Users" Dashboard Area - BP Extended Profiles (WordPress)

Tags: users, user-meta, wp-list-table

I have a site with extended profile fields. I can't find the particular way of adding an additional column as:

Username | Name | Email | Site Role | Discord (this is the additional column)

The extended profile has a text field called "Discord". How do I go on about making it display in one of the columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an extra column to the user list in WordPress, you can follow these steps:

- Register a Settings Page: Start by creating a settings page where you can define
  the additional columns you want to add. This page will allow you to manage the
  custom columns effectively.
- Save Custom Column Names: On the settings page, provide a text input
  where you can enter the names of the custom columns you want to add.
  Separate the column names with commas.
- Display the Custom Column: To display the custom column in the user
  list, you'll need to hook into [the `manage_users_columns` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_screen-id_columns/). Use
  this filter to add your custom columns to the list of columns.
- Populate Column Data: When displaying user data in your custom
  column, you can use [the `manage_users_custom_column` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_users_custom_column/). This
  filter lets you customize the content of your custom column for each
  user.
- Collect User Data: To collect data for the custom column, you'll need
  to update user metadata. You can use actions like [`user_register`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/) (for
  new user registration) or [`edit_user_profile_update`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/edit_user_profile_update/) (for profile
  updates) to save the data to user meta.
- Editing User Profiles: When adding new users or editing existing
  profiles, you should provide input fields for the custom columns on
  the user creation/editing pages.

If you'd like a practical example to see how these steps come together, you can refer to this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/WpNizzle/User-Column-Manager) . This repository contains a sample plugin i have created that demonstrates how to add and manage additional columns in the user list using WordPress hooks and filters. It serves as a helpful reference for implementing this feature on your site.

By following these general steps and referring to the provided example, you can add custom columns to the user list in WordPress and display additional information tailored to your site's needs.